# Every second message gets send to sender instead of receiver in UDP client-server-client implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, udp

I have decided to implement a simple client-server-client implementation utilizing multithreading. The problem I encountered is that the every second message sent from client A to client B goes back to the client A. I am not entirely sure why is that happening. My educated guess is the combination of multithreading and sender IPEndPoint passed as reference, however I don't really see any way to workaround the reference. Here are snippets of the code:

Server code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UDP
{
public sealed class UdpServer
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 12345);
        var udpServer = new UdpClient(ipEndPoint);

        var clientOne = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 12346);
        var clientTwo = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 12347);
        
        var taskFactory = new TaskFactory();
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
    
        var taskArray = new Task[2];
        taskArray[0] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => MessagingTask(udpServer, clientOne, clientTwo, tokenSource, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        taskArray[1] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => MessagingTask(udpServer, clientTwo, clientOne,  tokenSource, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);

        Task.WaitAny(taskArray);
    }

    private static void MessagingTask(UdpClient udpServer, IPEndPoint sender, IPEndPoint receiver, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var bytes = udpServer.Receive(ref sender);
            var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            Console.WriteLine($"IP: {sender.Address} Port: {sender.Port}, {DateTime.Now}: {message}");
            
            udpServer.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, receiver);
            Console.WriteLine($"Send to: {receiver.Address} Port: {receiver.Port}, {DateTime.Now}: {message}");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Client code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UDP
{
public sealed class UdpClientOne
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var clientEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 12346);
        var serverEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 12345);
        var udpClient = new UdpClient(clientEndpoint);
        
        var taskFactory = new TaskFactory();
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
    
        var taskArray = new Task[2];
        taskArray[0] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => ReadingThread(udpClient, serverEndpoint, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        taskArray[1] = taskFactory.StartNew(() => SendingThread(udpClient, serverEndpoint, tokenSource, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        
        Task.WaitAny(taskArray);
        
        udpClient.Close();
    }

    private static void ReadingThread(UdpClient udpClient, IPEndPoint ipEndPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Closing application...");
                return;
            }
           
            var data = udpClient.Receive(ref ipEndPoint);
            var message= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: {message}");
        }
    }

    private static void SendingThread(UdpClient udpClient, IPEndPoint ipEndPoint, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string userInput = "";
        
        while (true)
        {
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
                continue;

            if (userInput.Equals("q"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Closing application...");
                tokenSource.Cancel();
            }

            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userInput);
            udpClient.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, ipEndPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Console output:

[image: Console output]

Comment: It is in the server code : udpServer.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, receiver);

Comment: @jdweng But that's what I want isn't it? I want to send from client A to server and from server to client B. What else to place in there if not receiver?

Comment: You need two sockets (UdpServer) at server.  How does the server know to send to A or to send to B.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely. It took me a while to understand what happens and you are absolutely right. I was confused beacuse I was previously working on TCP server and the AcceptTcpClient returned proper sockets explicitly and since UDP is connectionless that's what confused me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UdpServer`'s server (port number: **12345**) is receiving the message from Client A (port number: **12346**) and then forwarded to Client B (port number: **12347**). However the `UdpClientOne`'s server ***sends*** data to the Client A and ***receives*** data from the Client A as well.

[image]

In the picture the blue color represents the `UdpServer` class and the red color represents the `UdpClientOne` class. Two arrow pointing to the Server (**12345** port), hence it will receive the message two times.

Comment: Thank you for your visualization. It helped me a lot. I resolved the problem by creating additional socket on the server as suggested by @jdwend